# Negating Definition of a Norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I have been trying the following question:

Let $X$ be the real vector space of continuous functions $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}.$ Show that setting $\| f \| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-2}|f(\frac{1}{n})|$ does not define a norm.

As far as I can tell this satisfies the triangle inequality and also $\|\lambda f\| = |\lambda|\|f\|.$ I assume that the negation must lie in the fact that $\|f\| = 0 $ does not imply that $f=0$, but honestly am unsure.

$\|f\| = 0 $ implies $ |f(\frac{1}{n})| = 0 $ and thus $ f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0 $ $ \forall n $. Is it because $f(x)$ could be non-zero elsewhere, e.g. on $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, $\|\cdot\|$ is a seminorm, but not a norm as it is not separating. Indeed, exactly as you say, there's a non-zero vector who is assigned zero length. As an example one can take any continuous function supported in $[1/2,1]$.

Comment: Also, there exists $f\in X$ such that $\|f\|=+\infty$

Comment: @Basti: $f$ is continuous and hence bounded in absolute value by some $M$. Then $\|f\| \le M\sum\frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$. Am I missing anything?

Comment: no, you are right